# undefined reference to `gHotSpotVMStructs' while compiling

Tags: c++, cmake

I tried to change value of `gHotSpotVMStructs` to 0 to prevent using HotSpot Debugger but while i tried to compile my code - my compiler thrown an error

```
CMakeFiles\JavaHotspotAttachCrasher.dir/objects.a(library.cpp.obj):library.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.gHotSpotVMStructs[.refptr.gHotSpotVMStructs]+0x0): undefined reference to gHotSpotVMStructs
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\JavaHotspotAttachCrasher.dir\build.make:96: libJavaHotspotAttachCrasher.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:110: CMakeFiles/JavaHotspotAttachCrasher.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:117: CMakeFiles/JavaHotspotAttachCrasher.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: JavaHotspotAttachCrasher] Error 2
```

My CMAKE file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(JavaHotspotAttachCrasher)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-s -O3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories("C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_311/jre/bin/server")

add_library(SecretLib SHARED "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_311/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll")
set_target_properties(SecretLib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)


add_library(JavaHotspotAttachCrasher SHARED library.cpp)

target_link_libraries(JavaHotspotAttachCrasher SecretLib)
```

My C++ file

```
#include <iostream>
extern void *gHotSpotVMStructs;

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Disabled gHotSpot" << std::endl;
    gHotSpotVMStructs = 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to compile it?

Comment: According to your code, you intended to make library `SecretLib` target to reflect the **external library** `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_311/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll`, but you actually defined an empty library. Needing to set `LINKER_LANGUAGE` property should signal you that something goes wrong, but you ignored that signal. The library needs to be `IMPORTED`. See duplicate question and its answers for more details.

Comment: @Tsyvarev i added that and i got an error

```# Your-external "mylib", add GLOBAL if the imported library is located in directories above the current.
add_library(mylib SHARED IMPORTED)
# You can define two import-locations: one for debug and one for release.
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_311/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(JavaHotspotAttachCrasher mylib)```

Error:
`CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "mylib" configuration "Debug".`

Comment: On Windows you cannot directly link with `.dll` file. You need to link with `.lib` file, which represents "import library". See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845886/linking-dll-in-visual-studio

Comment: @Tsyvarev but how i can use then jvm.dll 
I tried to use that method: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056863/disable-classdump-to-a-running-jvm-process-by-using-sa-jli)

nvm solved

Comment: But the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48066590/3440745) doesn't link with `jvm.dll`. You could create your library `JavaHotspotAttachCrasher` as MODULE (instead of SHARED): for such libraries undefined symbols are not checked. Note also, that referenced answer creates C library (not C++) and uses `-nostdlib` flag to not link with the standard library.